# Semanic UI dropdown with JQuery - How to initialize a semantic-ui dropdown with JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, drop-down-menu, semantic-ui

I have an array like this

```
var resultsArray = [ { name: "BMW", value: "BMW", text: "BMW" }, { name: "Mercedes-Benz", value: "Mercedes-Benz", text: "Mercedes-Benz" } ... ];
```

And then in my JavaScript, I tried to initialize the drop-down with above array.

```
 $('.select-car-model').dropdown({
                               source: resultsArray
                               });
```

However, the array is not populating the data. What am I missing here?

EDIT: This is the HTML

```
<select name="cars" class="ui search selection dropdown select-car-model" multiple="" id="car-multiselect">
```

Comment: Can you post the HTML?

Comment: Updated the main post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you're getting your options data from an API call, Semantic-UI doesn't have a setting to provide the options programmatically.  So really you just need to setup the select like you would normally

```
<select name="cars" class="ui search selection dropdown select-car-model" multiple="" id="car-multiselect">
  <option value="">Select Car</option>
  <option value="BMW">BMW</option>
  <option value="Mercedes-Benz">Mercedes-Benz</option>
</select>
```

And then to initialize Semantic-UI its just `$('.select-car-model').dropdown()`

If you happened to be using some sort of framework, or just jquery, you could programmatically add those options.  Just be sure to do it **before** the `dropdown()` call.

```
var resultsArray = [ { value: "BMW", text: "BMW" }, { value: "Mercedes-Benz", text: "Mercedes-Benz" } ... ];

$.each(resultsArray, function (i, item) {
  $('.select-car-model').append($('<option>', {
    value: item.value,
    text: item.text
  }))
})

$('.select-car-model').dropdown()
```